# Adjust width and height when appended to the end of a URL in a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, embed

I am embedding some videos in landing pages. I am trying to responsively size the video in accordance to screen size via Media Queries. Great success with YouTube videos by just separating the width and height from the `<iframe>`. I have come across a video now hosted by Ooyala.com, and their embed code utilizes a `<script>` tag with the height and width appended to the end of the URL.

e.g.

```
<script src="http:// player.ooyala.com/player.js?width=640&video_pcode=xxxxxx&embedCode=xxxxxx&height=360xxxxxx"><script>
```

I know this is JavaScript, but not familiar enough with JavaScript to know if I can somehow separate the width and height and incorporate it into the CSS, or if there is a way to set it in the JavaScript that will change it to 3 different size points based on screen size.

I am looking to start with the standard W=640 H=360, my next points will be W=390 H-219, & W=250 H=141.

Any JS guru's that can help me out on this one. All intelligence is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) for techniques on parsing a query string into JavaScript variables.

Comment: I'd suggest first figuring out exactly how that script tag results in a video appearing on the page with the given width/height. Does it create an iframe? create an embed code? create a video player? If it creates an iframe, all you need to do is target it and remove the set width/height from the tag after it has been created.

Comment: Hey Kevin, that is the actual embed code. That is the code I get when I click on the embed feature in the actual video. So this is the only associated code to the video within my landing page. I suppose the other appendages (&video_pcode=xxxx&deepLinkEmbedCode=xxxx) bring the player and link to the video. And obviously, let those x's=strings that I am removing as not to eat up a bunch of space.

Comment: Taking my upvote away because of lack of communication with those trying to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

That script will render a player in a div which you can then style using your own stylesheet - you just need to inspect the player so that you can see the id or class to use in your CSS. Ooyala provides details about customizing player styles, including width and height, [here](http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/reference/player_v3_dev_uicontrols.html).

Comment: Good thought and informative piece of documentation, but when I pull the width and height out of the query string the player defaults to a smaller size within the sized <div>

Answer (score 1):

You can create the script tag dynamically...

```
var video_script = document.createElement('script');
var the_width_you_want = 640;
var the_heigth_you_want = 360;
var video_src = 'http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?width=' + the_width_you_want +'&video_pcode=xxxxxx&embedCode=xxxxxx&height=' + the_heigth_you_want +'xxxxxx';
video_script.setAttribute('src', video_src);
element_to_append_to.appendChild(video_script);
```

Comment: Hey Jeremy, apologies for the delay. Got pulled for an alternate week ending project and derailed for a few. This is intriguing, but perhaps above my knowledge. I kind of understand what is going on here, but not sure how to translate it into 3 sizes depending on screen size and media query points. i.e. if screen size is >800px pass variable 640, if screen <800 but >360 pass variable 290... etc. If you're still out there and interested, appreciate your expertise.